# How to version controlling for different branches in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

How to version controlling for different branches in Bitbucket.
I want version controlling for different branches like production, stagging, development.
Is it possible in Bitbucket? If not then what I have to do?
Is there any platform that provides this solution? 
Please suggest me here.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, bitbucket uses git branches... I'm not sure I really got the point of your question.

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense. I'd suggest you have a read about GIT what it is, what it does, etc. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics The whole point of GIT is branching

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy different versions of branches using [Octopus](https://octopus.com/). You can build the different *versions* you want deployed with something like [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) or [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/).

You can set up Jenkins or TeamCity to automatically build and deploy everytime you update the master branch in Git. BitBucket is used on top of git, and is not used to control which version of some branch is deployed to some environment. Octupus + Jenkins/TeamCity is widely used for that purpose.